# custom itemscontrol for metro: uniformgrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, microsoft-metro

I need to create UniformGrid analog for metro.

I wrote this

```
public class UniformGrid : Panel
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalCountProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HorizontalCount", typeof (int), typeof (UniformGrid),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(default(int)));

    public int HorizontalCount
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue(HorizontalCountProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HorizontalCountProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ElementsGapProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ElementsGap", typeof (double), typeof (UniformGrid),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

    public double ElementsGap
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue(ElementsGapProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ElementsGapProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        return new Size();
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        if (Children != null && Children.Count != 0)
        {
            var squareSideForElement = (finalSize.Width - (HorizontalCount - 1)*ElementsGap)/HorizontalCount;
            var sizeOfElement = new Size(squareSideForElement, squareSideForElement);
            for (var i = 0; i < Children.Count; i++)
            {
                var rowIndex = i%HorizontalCount;
                var columnIndex = i/HorizontalCount;
                var resultPoint = new Point
                    {
                        X = rowIndex*(squareSideForElement + ElementsGap),
                        Y = columnIndex*(squareSideForElement + ElementsGap)
                    };
                Children[i].Arrange(new Rect(resultPoint, sizeOfElement));

            }

        }
        return finalSize;
    }
}
```

But after I understood that I need control derived from ItemsControl because I need ItemTemplate, ItemsSource etc.

I made this

```
public class UniformGrid : ItemsControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalCountProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HorizontalCount", typeof (int), typeof (UniformGrid),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(default(int)));

    public int HorizontalCount
    {
        get { return (int) GetValue(HorizontalCountProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HorizontalCountProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ElementsGapProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ElementsGap", typeof (double), typeof (UniformGrid),
                                    new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

    public double ElementsGap
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue(ElementsGapProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ElementsGapProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        return new Size();
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        if (Items != null && Items.Count != 0)
        {
            var squareSideForElement = (finalSize.Width - (HorizontalCount - 1)*ElementsGap)/HorizontalCount;
            var sizeOfElement = new Size(squareSideForElement, squareSideForElement);
            for (var i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
            {
                var rowIndex = i%HorizontalCount;
                var columnIndex = i/HorizontalCount;
                var resultPoint = new Point
                    {
                        X = rowIndex*(squareSideForElement + ElementsGap),
                        Y = columnIndex*(squareSideForElement + ElementsGap)
                    };
                Items[i].Arrange(new Rect(resultPoint, sizeOfElement));

            }

        }
        return finalSize;
    }
}
```

But I have error on line

```
Items[i].Arrange(new Rect(resultPoint, sizeOfElement));
```

I understand reason of this errors.

My questions are

1) How can I get item template for this item filled with data provided by binding?

2) Is there need to call Measure for every item in MeasureOverride?

Comment: why not use itemscontrol with the panel you started with as itemspanel? , yes you need to measure every item

Comment: ZSH Please write as answer how can I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- your item template-->
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
```